# From Column headers to column value

Tags: python, transpose

I transpose a DF which columns where dates and rows variables. So it's now has the forms of Dates as column head (but I want them to be a column value named Date) and the rows are now columns.

How can I move from column headers to column vuales so the date which was originally header and is now and index transform it into a new variables which has the name "Date", thank you

Current:

```
df
   c  d
a  1  2
b  3  4
```

I would like to get this:

```
df
  col1 col2  col3
0    a    c     1
1    a    d     2
2    b    c     3
3    b    d     4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You might want to rename the column after

```
df.stack().reset_index()
```

to rename your column you can also try using the rename()

```
df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns= {'level_0':'col1','level_1':'col2',0:'col3'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Current `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'c': 1, 'd': 2},
    {'c': 3, 'd': 4}], index=['a', 'b'])

  c d 
a 1 2 
b 3 4
```

Desired `df`

```
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

[image]

Comment: You literally wrote the same answer as i did. You could have as well edited mine  rather than duplicate  it

Comment: Be a good sport! I did *not* notice your solution when busy working on mine. Besides, our methods are different: `df.rename(columns= {'level_0':'col1','level_1':'col2',0:'col3'})` vs `df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']`